# Flash memory power consumption

Tags: batteries, flash, cellphone

I would like to know how much power does a flash memory chip consume, and whether it is viable for use when the device is switched off since I will require R/W access to the chip when switched off. Device in question is a cell phone, about 2000 mAh.

Is there any other power-saving alternative available other than flash memory? I want the chip to eat only as much power as a cell phone's clock requires, or lesser, since it has to work when switched off as well.

Comment: CMOS SRAM would consume less energy per write cycle than flash EPROM, but it would lose its data if the battery were ever disconnected. This doesn't sound like it would be much of an issue for you, though.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to be able to access a flash memory chip (or any IC for that matter) when it is switched off.

Answer (score 1):

A flash chip requires power for either read or write access.  The power advantage of flash comes from it being non-volatile.  That is, it needs no power in order to retain the information on it, once programmed. How much power a flash chip consumes depends on what operation is being called.  A write takes about 60 mA at 3 V for up to 3 msec (MLC NAND) That will program a single 16K byte page.

If you do not need large storage density, you can consider PCM memory.  It is faster than NAND and byte addressable.  For more detailed information go to a memory vendor;s website, such as Micron.com, Samsung.com and look for their publid NAND and PCM memory specifications.  these contain information on programming time, read time, how to address them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [FRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectric_RAM) (ferroelectric RAM) that is nonvolatile, and it also requires much less write energy than flash EPROM.